# OpenID for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I saw many links over the internet and specifically openid-consumer project (which is a part of http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/), but it doesn't work as honestly readme file says.

So what's the latest update on that? Is there any way I can authenticate my web site users with OpenID from someone besides Google (like stackoverflow does)?

Answer (score 3):

I have setup an example app here:

http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example

With the source code. It works exactly the way stackoverflow does. Have not implemented facebook auth as its buggy still.

Comment: Did u try it on your own domain?

Comment: No I meant on your domain like www.domain.com. It works on local machine for me too, but not on hosting.

Comment: I have hosted the same on http://testingauth.heroku.com And yes it works for me when hosted too.

Answer (score 2):

I've just played a bit with the openid-consumer you mention and it actually works. Have you tried to run the sample code standalone, as a separate project?

I've used it in a test application on App Engine and it seems to work alright. I placed the consumer.py, fetcher.py, store.py and then the openid dir in the root dir, then I moved parts of the config in app.yaml from the openid sample app to my app.yaml.

You can check the implementation at http://x-libris.appspot.com. In the upper right corner press *Logga in* (which is swedish for login). Try using any of the available OpenId providers, so far OpenId, Google, MySpace and Yahoo! are available (I've only tested the first two providers).

It's an Ajax based solution so I did some tweaking of the render method in consumer.py in order to change the templating and the example at openid-demo.appspot.com was handy.

// John

Comment: It works sometimes as I understand, but you can't rely on it - I haven't seen any message from Google Support that they fixed the bug with URL fetching.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed the new version of the app engine SDK now includes support for OpenID in the user API

> The 1.3.4 release includes support for authentication via OpenID as an experimental feature.

look [in the app engine python user API docs](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/users/) for more info about this

This should make this easy to implement (I will start implementing this today !)

Comment: Any results that you may be able to share regarding this?

Comment: is this still experimental feature in GAE SDK 1.4.0?

Answer (score 1):

try rpxnow.com , they provide multiple options including openid.