# OpenID consumer for JAVA GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

Is there any OpenID implementation I could use in my GAE (Google App Engine) Project?

Comment: previous question almost exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590897/openid-for-google-app-engine

Comment: @Peter the other question was related to GAE/Python, here it is Java

Answer (score 2):

I think it is now supported by GAE sdk
http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/articles/openid.html

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use RPX which allows your application to accept OpenID from multiple sources without you having to do the hard work.

I have used it for my GAE app, even jusing GWT and it works well.

[rpxnow.com](http://rpxnow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that openid4java does *not* work with GAE since GAE excludes certain redirects.  See: [link text](http://aralbalkan.com/1357)

Comment: Correction. This seems to be supported now with a recent change to openid4java: http://opensource.bamboo.atlassian.com/browse/OPENID-OPENID4JAVA-338/commit

Answer (score 0):

Combine Spring security, OpenID4java and [Step2](http://code.google.com/p/step2/). It seems to work. I haven't deployed it to appspot, but it worked on Eclipse + GAE.

Comment: Spring Security's integrated OpenID support doesn't work on App Engine. OpenID4Java tries to spawn a thread to make an HTTP request which App Engine doesn't allow.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180354/spring-security-openid-on-google-app-engine and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620823/accesscontrolexception-when-using-spring-security-with-openid